# CSS Columns flicking

Tags: html, css

I'm having a hard time to setup a column-based layout with only CSS. The thing is that in Google Chrome the columns always "flick" (disappear, reappear) at a certain action (slider above is moving).

This is my Code for the Columns

**HTML**

```
<ul class="posts column-count-2 format-list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.column-count-2 {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
```

You can see an live example here: http://dev.anex.at/kolarik/dev/

Did someone already had this issue? How can this be solved?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: A similar problem happens on my site, when content elsewhere shifts by a pixel whenever some other element performs a little "shake" animation. As far as I can tell, this is an error in Chrome, especially because `transform` does not affect the flow! So... unfortunately I don't really know how to help with this, other than maybe check to ensure everything is aligned to an exact pixel value...

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle showcasing this issue? Your site may change or go down in the future, and won't help future users who have a similar issue.

Comment: @badAdviceGuy your name should be goodAdviceGuy :-)

Comment: @badAdviceGuy yes will do that shortly. In the meantime I found out that this issue has something to do with an element inside the LI which has position: relative.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Try adding `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to the affected element, I had the same problem in Chrome and fixed it with that.

Comment: @Adrift genious...that solved my issue as well. Thanks for sharing.